# cuda segmentation fault

Tags: c, cuda

I am programming with cuda in C. I got a segmentation fault with the code lines following:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

// load input image
unsigned char * image_input = loadFile(&width, &height, "test.bmp");

// allocate memory for output
unsigned char * image_output = (unsigned char *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(unsigned char));

// set the size of the input and out array 2D
int size = width*height*sizeof(int);

// Allocate space on the GPU for input and output
char* GPU_input = 0;
char* GPU_output = 0;   

cudaMalloc(&GPU_input, size);       
cudaMalloc(&GPU_output, size);

// Copy the input data to the GPU (host to device)
cudaMemcpy(GPU_input, image_input, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //segmentation fault here
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Size is sizeof(int) *H*W. (in bytes)
- Image_input is H*W. (in bytes)

You are addressing image_input beyond its size.

Comment: Hi wildplasser, so what should I change? I am not clear. thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you intend to do. You have two types of arrays: one consisting of characters, the other of ints. I don't know what your CUDA-thingy expects. (but I suspects ints)

Comment: yes, it was a mistake. I changed it to size of (char). sovlved the problem. thanks!